# How to log in JSON with Logback?

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

I'm new to SLF4J and Logback and I'm trying to log every request and response of API following this [link](https://pivotal.io/de/application-transformation-recipes/observability/request-response-logging-in-spring-boot). Here's the configuration

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%requestURL | status code: %statusCode | bytes: %bytesSent | elapsed time: %elapsedTime | request-log: %magenta(%requestContent) | response-log: %cyan(%responseContent)</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</configuration>
```

Currently it's printing:

```
GET /api/request HTTP/1.1 | status code: 200 | bytes: 599 | elapsed time: 2630 | request-log:  | response-log {"key1":"field1","key2":"field2"}
```

And I want to log something like:

```
{
    "url": "GET /api/request HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "elapsed_time": 2630 ,
    "response": {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using spring boot here is the best example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-slf4j-logging-example/

Comment: try this https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As I understand, the examples above are triggering logger by calling the logger methods. In my case, I'm using FilterRegistrationBean, therefore logger should be working automatically on each request.

Answer (score 5):

This would work:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <jsonFactoryDecorator class="JsonLogDecorator"/>
        <fieldNames>
            <timestamp>timeStamp</timestamp>
            <message>message</message>
            <logger>logger</logger>
            <thread>thread</thread>
            <level>level</level>
            <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
            <version>[ignore]</version>
            <stackTrace>stackTrace</stackTrace>
        </fieldNames>
        <includeMdcKeyName>mdcKeyToInclude</includeMdcKeyName>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

JsonLogDecorator is custom class that implements `JsonFactoryDecorator`.

Comment: The `JsonLogDecorator` class cannot be found, but otherwise this works well.