# This use of org/slf4j/Logger.info(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V might be used to include CRLF characters into log messages

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, logback, slf4j, crlf-vulnerability

I am getting this sonar issue(Security - Potential CRLF Injection for logs) while logging request body parameter in code.

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> someMethod(@RequestBody User user) {
 log.info("user received as --> {}", user);
}
```

How to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Please do something about the formatting, as I have no idea what you are posting.

Answer (score 1):

That is really annoying warning produced by `sonarqube`. The problem is `sonarqube` expects from you to write dumb code like:

```java
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> someMethod(@RequestBody User user) {
    log.info(
            "user received as --> {}", 
            String.valueOf(user)
                    .replace("\r", "\\r")
                    .replace("\n", "\\n")
    );
}
```

which is obviously unacceptable.

If your security team do believe CR/LF characters in logs is a real security problem the only correct approach is following:

- disable corresponding `sonarqube` checks
- properly setup logging subsystem, using one of the following ways:

  1. take advantage of `output encoding` in `logback` - for example, write all logs in JSON:

     - https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output
     - [How to log in JSON with Logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424249/how-to-log-in-json-with-logback)
  2. use [`security-logging-logback`](https://github.com/augustd/owasp-security-logging) library, [here](https://github.com/augustd/owasp-security-logging/blob/master/owasp-security-logging-logback/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml) is an example of corresponding `logback` configuration